# woocommerce shipping table rates per order + per cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce table rate shipping

In my current system I need to two types of shipping rates 
1.  Per Order (Based on category )
2.  Per Item (Based on category )
The both categories are working fine if the products are separately added
But while I am adding and one products from each categories, in that senarioes I want to both shipping method summation.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,

Denis

http://www.yiion.com

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Table Rate plugin from WooCommerce you have to check 'break' when setting up the shipping method.